# Generate a rails model with an array of floats as attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, migration

Disclaimer:  I am a newbie.

I am trying to create a User and save it to the database with a location attribute.  I want the location to be an array with the latitude and longitude of the user, which I want to pull from the browser using "navigator.geolocation.GetCurrentLocation()".

I created a User model and ran the following migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.float :location, array: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

If I pass it a float, it allows me to save it.  However, if I try to pass it two floats (lat and long) it throws an error ("no method to_f for "array").  Has anyone tried doing this before that could offer some assistance?  Thanks.

Comment: if you are using mysql you can't do this, it's only supported in postgresql

Comment: Thank you, I changed my adapter to postresql and it seems to be allowing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array data type is defined in the [postgres adapter](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array) but not mysql, there's quite a lot data types that are supported in postgres but not mysql, they're mentioned in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Array is differ from one Database to another. MySQL doesn't support arrays, but postgreSQL support.
Maybe some noSQL solutions support.